# Switch Between views in FrameLayout from a child view

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-linearlayout, surfaceview, android-framelayout

I currently have  a SurfaceView (named BoardView) that is being stored in a FrameLayout. There is another LinearLayout (l1) that is stored in this FrameLayout(f1) which contains an EditText. I want to be able to bring the EditText to the front from within my BoardView. Is this possible? I tried using getParent().bringChildToFront(); but it didn't work. Any ideas?

```
public class Board extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //use a frame layout so you can also display a dialog box
    // allows more than one view to be used
    FrameLayout f1 = new FrameLayout(this);
    LinearLayout l1 = new LinearLayout(this);
    EditText edit = new EditText(this);

    l1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    l1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    edit.setText("Enter your name!");
    l1.addView(edit);

    f1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    f1.addView(l1);
    f1.addView(new BoardView(this));

    setContentView(f1);

    //setContentView(new BoardView(this));
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds rather silly, but try `l1.bringToFront()` and see if that works? Alternatively just add `l1` second:

```
f1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    f1.addView(new BoardView(this));
    f1.addView(l1);
```

and the edit text will be on top.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: The thing is, it says "l1" cannot be resolved. I want to show l1 ONLY when something happens in the SurfaceView. Basically, when the game ends, I want to show this new View. I guess I could make the current view invisible, right?

Comment: Ah, so that is the question: show the code where you are making the switch

Comment: Well, the piece of code is rather long, really. I have a custom SurfaceView - there is not enough room to post the code here :/ What should I do to show you? My class title looks something like this.   public class BoardView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

Comment: Is there a problem because it is a custom class? Surely there must be some way to do this.

Comment: Shouldn't matter. The not resolve issue is just because your custom class doesn't have visibility of the `l1` object. I'd suggest assigning IDs to `l1` and then using the id: so do `l1.setId(1);` in the `onCreate` above and then in your custom class use `((View)getParent()).findViewById(1).bringToFront();` to update the z-order.

Comment: I tried using setVisiblity(INVISIBLE) from inside my surface view, but it only made my program force close. Is there a problem perhaps, because I have threads running?

Comment: No, I expect you're just not referencing the right view when you are bringing to the front.

Comment: Okay, i'm getting an error saying that it is being called from the wrong thread. "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views". I have posted a new topic so you can see all the code.      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928755/called-from-wrong-thread-exception

Comment: Ah. You're doing things on the wrong thread. Answered in the other thread.